# jQuery droppable not allowing dropping from certain origin container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm building an interface to assign shortcut buttons to a phone with 12 positions on the screen.

The first position is fixed and cannot be changed by the end-user, remaining slots are open for users to move their buttons around as they want. Each of the 12 positions can have either 0 or 1 users assigned, so I've got logic in place to prevent two users being dropped in the same slot.

The issue I'm hitting is that if a user starts in the 'Assigned' part, then there's no problem with dragging and dropping them to another 'Assigned' slot, but if I move an 'Assigned' one to the 'Available' group or try to move one that started in the 'Available' group to an 'Assigned' slot, it won't let me drop the user.

The set up I'm using at present is as follows, with simplified HTML for clarity.
For a full example of what I'm trying, check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgg8nhhd/3/).

```
<div id="centrex_users_devices_buttons_edit">
    <h4>Available Users</h4>
    <ul>
            <li data-user-id="23">Widget Co Main</li>
            <li data-user-id="32">Initech Main</li>
            <li data-user-id="410">0064123456789</li>
    </ul>

    <h4>Assigned Users</h4>
    <ul class="draggable-placeholders">
      <li class="placeholder">
        <span class="placeholder-pos">1</span>
        <ul class="draggable single-only">
            <li class="ui-state-default static_centrex_device_button">Ben Smith</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="placeholder">
        <span class="placeholder-pos">2</span>
        <ul class="draggable single-only">
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="placeholder">
        <span class="placeholder-pos">3</span>
        <ul class="draggable single-only">
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
var outer_id = '#centrex_users_devices_buttons_edit';
var outer = $(outer_id);
$.each(outer.find('.draggable'),function (j, val){
    $(val).droppable({
        accept: outer_id + ' .draggable li',
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function(event,ui){
            ui.draggable.addClass( 'dropped' );
            ui.draggable.data('droppedin',$(this));
            if ($(this).hasClass('single-only')) {
                $(this).droppable('disable');
            }
            $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(this);
        }
    }).disableSelection();
    if ($(val).hasClass('single-only') && $(val).find('li').length) $(val).droppable('disable');
    $.each($(val).find('li'), function(){
        $(this).data('droppedin',$(val));
    });
});
$(outer_id + ' .draggable li:not(.static_centrex_device_button)').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    drag: function(event,ui){
        if( $(this).data('droppedin') ){
            $(this).data('droppedin').droppable('enable');
            $(this).data('droppedin',null);
            $(this).removeClass( 'dropped' );
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be something which as far as I can see is undocumented in that the object being dropped in the container must be smaller in dimensions than the container; this meant the `li`s that I had in my "Available" container which were wider than the "Assigned" slots couldn't be placed in there, but anything already in an "Assigned" slot was the correct width so could be moved to either location.